# DateTime Format for .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

By using the following code, how do I get the date format to be mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM|PM?

```
string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64.aspx

Comment: I'm sure this is a duplicate, I am just not sure that I can be bothered to go find what for. OP: have you just googled for an answer?

Comment: Zero research or effort, -1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var res = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Read [**Standard Date and Time Format Strings**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) On MSDN for more information

Below is another way of achieving same format

```
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("G", 
                  CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")));
// Displays 4/10/2008 6:30:00 AM
```

Comment: `.ToString("G")` looks like it might be worth mentioning too with reference to locales, etc. (ie it should work for en-us).

Comment: Yes I noticed I had to switch it around to string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"); too. Thx.

Comment: This will give the requested result if the current locale is English, but, for example, will give MM.dd.yyyy ... in Germany, because / represents a culture-specific date separator.  Better to specify CultureInfo.InvariantCulture explicitly.